# Suggest code improvements: Count instances of words while ignoring punctuation and common words

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary, tuples

This point of this program is to count occurrences of words while ignoring punctuation and articles and conjunctions. The desired output is a list of top 15 words used and bottom 15 words used without showing their occurrences. I'm a beginner and any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
# This program reads a text file, performs a content analysis
# and prints both a top 15 and a bottom 15 report

name = input('Enter name of file: ')

 # Clean Function
def clean(s):
    punctuations = ["!","@","#","$"]
    art_con = ['the','a','an','some','and','but','or','nor','for']
    for each in punctuations:
        s = s.replace(each,"")
    words = s.split()
    resultwords = [word for word in words if word.lower() not in art_con]
    result= ''.join(resultwords)
    return result

# Analyze Function
def analyze(name):
    print('Reading',name,'for analysis...')
    print('===========================')
    print('Creating content analysis dictionary...')
    r = open(name, 'r')
    s = r.read()
    result = clean(s)
    count = dict((x,result.count(x)) for x in set(result))
    print('Analysis complete!')
    print('===================')
    return count

count = analyze(name)

# turn dictionary into a list of tuples to sort
def function(count):
    list1 = []
    for key in count:
        t = (count[key],key)
        list1.append((t))
    list1.sort()
    result = [list1[i] for i in range(len(list1))]
    t15 = result[0:15]
    b15 = result[-15:0]
    print("The top 15 words are ",t15)
    print("The bottom 15 words are ",b15)

#Main Function
def main():
    count = analyze(name)
    function(count)
main()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Okay… and what's your question?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm a beginner and any help would be much appreciated.

Overall, the code looks nice.  The *clean()* function could be made faster and more concise by 1) lower-casing the input string at the outset, 2) using regular expressions to extract the words while ignoring punctuation, and 3) eliminating the common words using the set-difference operation.

Here is a rough-cut to get you started:

```
words = re.findall(r"[a-z\'\-]+", s.lower())
return set(words) - {'the','a','an','some','and','but','or','nor','for'}
```